# Google like auto search text functionality in windows phone 8 using MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need Google like auto complete search text functionality in Windows Phone 8 using MVVM. Please can any one having good experience in windows phone 8 help me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb8b6ff3-44b4-4e17-8095-dd75783f2012/google-like-auto-complete-search-list-in-winodows-phone-8

Hope it will help others.